Using IRC how can I get a list of current viewers of my twitch stream?
Using twitches IRC API I am trying to get all the current viewers of my stream when the bot runs however on_names never runs even though when the bot connects it should receive JOIN, 353 and 366 messages but only on_join is executed. (pubmsg, welcome, and join all work)
import irc.client

def on_connect(connection, event):
    logging.info(f"Connected to {connection.server}")
    connection.join(channel)


def on_join(connection, event):
    logging.info(f"Joined {channel}")
    logging.info(f"event: {event}")


def on_names(connection, event):
    logging.info(f"Received raw message: {event} - Type: {event.type}")

    # Check for NAMES response
    if event.type == "353":  # NAMES reply
        # Format: :tmi.twitch.tv 353 <bot_nick> = <channel> :<names>
        channel = event.arguments[1]
        names = event.arguments[2].split()
        global viewers
        viewers = names
        logging.info(f"Updated list of viewers in {channel}: {viewers}")

    elif event.type == "366":  # End of NAMES reply
        logging.info(f"End of NAMES list for {event.arguments[1]}.")


def run_irc_bot(server, port, nickname, token):
    reactor = irc.client.Reactor()
    factory = irc.connection.Factory(wrapper=ssl.wrap_socket)

    try:
        logging.info("Connecting to chat...")
        connection = reactor.server().connect(server, port, nickname, token, connect_factory=factory)
        logging.info(f"Connected to {server} as {nickname}")
    except irc.client.ServerConnectionError as e:
        logging.error(f"Could not connect to server: {e}")
        return

    connection.add_global_handler('welcome', on_connect)
    connection.add_global_handler('join', on_join)
    connection.add_global_handler('pubmsg', on_pubmsg)
    connection.add_global_handler(353, on_names)
    connection.add_global_handler(366, on_names)

    try:
        reactor.process_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logging.info("Shutting down...")
    finally:
        connection.close()
        logging.info("Bot disconnected.")

I have also tried
connection.add_global_handler('names', on_names)

connection.add_global_handler('353', on_names)
connection.add_global_handler('366', on_names)


I don't use twitch. I mainly used plain irc. Did you join Channel? Haven't you read RFC1459?

I got it working. I do join the channel. No I have not read RFC1459 I shall read that now.

Solution I found
connection.add_global_handler('namreply', on_names)
connection.add_global_handler('endofnames', on_names)

def on_names(connection, event):
    # Check for NAMES response
    if event.type == "namreply":  # NAMES reply
        channel = event.arguments[1]
        username = event.arguments[2].split()
        #do what you want with this info I made a class called viewers and this creates a viewer
        viewer = Viewer(username)

    elif event.type == "endofnames":  # End of NAMES reply
        logging.info(f"End of NAMES list for {event.arguments[1]}.")

To get all events from twitch
connection.add_global_handler('all_events', on_any_event)

def on_any_event(connection, event):
    logging.info(f"Event received: {event.type} - Arguments: {event.arguments})

